# LightGBM Installation issue on cmake

Tags: cmake, homebrew, lightgbm

I would like to download LightGbm and i followed this website for doing it. But suddenly stopped with an error. Please post a solution.

Thankshttps://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#macos

Error:

```
cmake ..
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  gcc-7.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/kj/LightGBM/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Please don’t use the [tag:brew] tag; it has nothing to do with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Your environment variable CC is set to `gcc-7` but this compiler can't be access with your $PATH variable.

Try to write `gcc-7` in a terminal you should get a `Command not found` error.

Comment: Yes, it says not found so what could be the solution

Comment: The solution is to change the value of the CC environment variable with : `export CC={path_to_your_compiler}`

Comment: Could you please be more brief on how to change it.

Comment: You change his value with export CC={path_to_your_compiler} and you launch CMake again or you add this value directly in your .bashrc in your home.